# Constrained surface (multidimensional) integration

Tags: probability, integration, algorithms

I'm trying to implement a program that performs surface integration, i.e., it computes $\int_S f(s) dS$. My goal is to apply it to compute cumulative density functions (but i'm looking for a genneral solution). For example, suppose i have 3 variables with the following distributions: $X \sim gaussian(0,1)$, $Y \sim gaussian(0,2)$ and $Z \sim gaussian(0,3)$ and some constraints, let's say $X > Y + Z$, $Y > 3$ and $Z > Y$ (both distribution types and constraints are here just to provide a concrete examples, the bistribution do not need to be all of the same type). Now, if i want to compute $\int_S f(x,y,z) dxdydz$ where $S$ is the surface identified by the constraints. How can i do it? Is there a general algorithm to compute exact and/or approximate solutions? If there are only constraints that involve a single variable, i.e. $Y > 3$, it is easy since i need to integrate this variable in $[3,\infty]$, but how can i integrate when there are constraints with more than one variable involved, i.e., $X > Y$?
For approximate solutions, i know, for example, Monte Carlo methods. However, it is not clear to me how to apply them in a *constrained surface* such as the one i've described. Any hint and/or explanation on a running example is very apreciated.

Comment: A $2$D surface has measure $0$ in $\mathbb{R}^3$ so the integral, at least as stated above, will be $0$. Could you clarify what you mean by the integral along a constrained surface?

Comment: I mean surface in $R^n$. If you consider 2d, it is simple to imagine since you have only constraints involving x and y.

Comment: when you're randomly sampling the surface, you can use simple rejection test to include constraints to the system. When boolean expression x>y fails, then the sample can be rejected and otherwise included to the results.

Comment: Ok but rejection sampling may discard a lot of samples if the probability is low